# How to increase Chrome's connections-per-server?

Tags: google-chrome, download

Google Chrome (by default) only allows 6 concurrent connections per server.

For example, when we download files from dropbox, we can only download a maximum of 6 files concurrently.

How do we change this limit such that we can download more files concurrently?

Comment: Maybe this will hold some answers for u? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098116/chromium-max-number-of-concurrent-http-connections

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm sorry but it would appear to be a hard limit according to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12066

Answer (score 14):

Actually you're limited per profile, not per browser.

All you have to do is to create several profiles, from the settings page. I have two for Facebook accounts, one for my sister and one for work. In total I could be able to download 18 files concurrently and all I have to do is to switch or bring up alongside a new Chrome profile in its own window from the top-left corner icon, viewable only when there are more than one profiles. And it's pretty fast as well, reuses Chrome apps (flash etc) and main exe so it's not like it's a whole new browser launched with it's own resources.

Unfortunately there's no other option...

Comment: This answer is still correct.  I recently downloaded 8 files in parallel, 6 using my primary profile's window, and an additional two in an incognito window.

Comment: You can add a person or profile in Google Chrome by following these steps - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en - and yes this works, I'm able to download six files per profile when using Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

As long as your connections are on HTTP2 (and not HTTP 1.1), then you're not affected by this limit.

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Comment: Just to be clear: you can not change this as a user, but you can implement your website differently if you're a web developer. This explains it better than I would: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36847527/217022

Comment: Oh gotcha, so the limit is still in effect if you're for instance using web-sockets and want multiple open (ie. two different services & servers).

Answer (score -1):

If you need to overcome the limit for testing purposes, you can open incognito window in Chrome.